# Flutter: Passing Data between Classes Resets the Other Value

Tags: flutter, dart, parameter-passing, navigator

I try to pass sRegions value from Regions class to the AddAd class
and passing sCategory value from Categories class to AddAd class

but when I click and pass this value , it resets the other value to initial value

I want to the values inside AddAd class to be separated and do not affect each other

Here is AddAd() class:

```
class AddAd extends StatefulWidget {

  final String sRegion;
  final String sCategory;

  AddAd(this.sRegion,this.sCategory, {Key key}):super(key: key);
  @override
  _AddAdState createState() => _AddAdState();
}

ListTile(
  title: Text("Location"),
  subtitle: widget.sRegion == null ? Text("Where exactly") : Text(widget.sRegion),
),

ListTile(
  title: Text("Category"),
  subtitle: widget.sCategory == null ? Text("Department") : Text(widget.sCategory),
),
```

and here is how I pass data from Regions class:

```
 child: Text(item),
 onPressed: () {
   sRegion = item;
   Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddAd(sRegion, sCategory)));
   print(sRegion);
 },
```

and here how I pass data from Categories class:

```dart
class _RegionsState extends State<Regions> {

  String sRegion;
  String sCategory;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Location"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Cancel', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>AddAd(sRegion, sCategory)));
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:15.0),
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  for(var item in regions) FlatButton(
                    child: Text(item), onPressed: (){
                      sRegion = item;
                      Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddAd(sRegion, sCategory)));
                      print(sRegion);
                  },),
                  Divider(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that somewhere in `Regions` clas you're reseting `sCategory` and somewhere inside `Categories` you're reseting `sRegion` but you don't show the complete code so it's hard to see where... maybe I'm not understanding correctly. Maybe you don't even set those values so they will be passed as null...

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I add the full code of Regions class and I just declare variable , nothing more

Comment: Does AddAd class have a place where the widget.sRegion/sCategory is changed?

Comment: @DelphiX No ijust declare them in the class and get the data from Navigaor

Comment: it would help if you could provide that code as well

Comment: @DelphiX I added the full code